# Current directory changes when I call PowerShell script from Command Prompt

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script which contains a single command:

```
pwd
```

When I execute it from a (Windows 10) command line window, I get the following:

```
d:\Hudson_Test\workspace\CadGraphics>echo %cd%
d:\Hudson_Test\workspace\CadGraphics

d:\Hudson_Test\workspace\CadGraphics>powershell -file ShowLocation.ps1

Path
----
D:\hudson_test\workspace
```

As you can see, the current directory moves up one directory (from d:\hudson_test\workspace\CadGraphics to D:\hudson_test\workspace) when inside the PowerShell script.

I tested this on another (Win10) machine, and on that machine, the two paths were the same.

What is going on here, and how can I keep it from happening?

Comment: Do you have a profile? `notepad $profile` to check.  Sounds like you have a profile that is setting the location.  You can launch powershell without executing your profile with `powershell -NoProfile -File ShowLocation.ps1`

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem even on Windows 10.

Comment: Yes, it was the profile that was causing the problem.  Launching powershell with the -NoProfile flag fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should not unless the Profile is loading it everytime. Please try with

> powershell -NoProfile -File FileName.ps1

Secondly , I would like you to store that in a variable and see the result from *write-host*

Comment: Yup.  It was loading a profile, which was setting its directory.

Comment: @PortMan:  Great: happy to help